# In Python why are we using command line so frequent?

Tags: python

Python have differences from other languages like C or Java. We are using using command line, downloading libraries, using pip... I want to know why python is different and how can I learn it's features (not coding).

Comment: It's relative to your development environment. 

Plenty of C developers use CLI. `gcc`/`make`. Java devs use `mvn` or `gradle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, a python program is not compiled, it's interpreted. This means that the computer read the lines of code one by one and executes them at the same time. Therefore, you can use Python to run one line commands such as `2*2` in a Python shell, which makes it convenient in some applications.

Pip is a tool to install modules, that you can later use in a Python program, instead if rewriting everything from scratch.